# Easiest way to read in numbers with script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am dealing with a .txt file with the following content:

```
###################################################
Optimization for H260_ptyy275tau42.475C1.08_Analyzed.root

SOME TEXT


ptyy > -25
Significance: 1.79789e-05 +- 7.31008e-08
N_sig: 3.30335e-05 +- 3.15914e-05; N_SMbkg: 1.61124 +- 0.0612171; N_yyBackground: 1.76462 +- 0.469689
Fit function f=exp(a+b*x) with a = 0.567933 +- 0.266166 and b = -1.58821e-09 +- 0.00982024
Fit = 1.76462+-0.469689, sbL = 21+-4.58258 & sbT = 1+-1

MORE TEXT AND NUMBERS
```

I now want to read in the numbers after N_sig until 0.469689, each in a different variable. What is the easiest way doint this with a .sh or python script?

Comment: It would be sed/awk

Comment: do you know that the desired text will always be on it's own line like in your example?

Comment: Are you forced to use bash/sh?  Bash (along with most Unix utilities AFAIK) does not know how to handle scientific notation, so you would have to parse and convert the numbers yourself.  This would be much easier in a modern scripting language like Python.

Comment: Python would be fine too.

Comment: @Mark In python, you  can use regular expressions with matching groups, then a simple cast to float will convert the scientific notation as a string to a `float`.

Comment: Why are the other answers deleted? I am having trouble using numbers = np.genfromtxt(sys.argv[1], usecols=1, dtype=float) as it returns something like this: [             nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan   1.79789000e-05   3.30335000e-05
              nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan   1.79784000e-05
  and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep, bash and an array:

```
mapfile -t array < <(grep ^N_sig file | grep -oE '[0-9.e-]{2,}')

declare -p array
```

Output:

```
declare -a array='([0]="3.30335e-05" [1]="3.15914e-05" [2]="1.61124" [3]="0.0612171" [4]="1.76462" [5]="0.469689")'
```

Comment: Good, but it is not tied to scientific notation, it will match any group that is made of at least 2 characters in the `0-9.e-` subset.

Comment: The following pattern should be used instead: `grep -oE '[\d.]+(?:e-?\d+)?'`

Comment: @Lovy: Thank you. I suggest to replace `E` (extended regular expression) by `P` (Perl regular expression) in your comment, too.